How can you limit grouped results?
in drupal 11 i have a view that lists results grouped by taxonomy term but i would like to limit the results in each group.
currently all the results are returned grouped by the taxonomy term but i would like to get 2 results per group is that possible to do in drupal without creating a view for each subprofile?
i am not familiar with the database structure to alter the query


This question is similar to: Limiting nodes returned per group in a view. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@monalisa i have too many subprofiles to create a view for each and unfortunately i am using drupal 11 that module does not work for me

the node id is returned but the data is empty, i just got the data from the node id using twig at the end, the groups are returned in views-view-unformatted--block.html.twig, and the results are in views-view-fields--block.html.twig, the default drupal behavior seems to work for results more than 2 but for 2 or less it has that bug
